# Spark EC2 support for Windows

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, apache-spark

All the documentation about deploying a *Spark* cluster on *Amazon EC2* is relative to Linux environments. However, my distributed project is, at this moment, dependent of some *Windows* functionalities, and I would like to start working with a *Windows* cluster while making the necessary changes.

I would like to know if there is any method that makes us able to deploy a *Windows Spark* cluster on EC2 in a way relatively similar to the `spark-ec2` script provided by *Spark*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spark-ec2` currently only supports launching clusters in EC2 using [specific Linux AMIs](https://github.com/mesos/spark-ec2/tree/v4/ami-list), so deploying a Windows Spark cluster is currently not possible using that tool. I doubt that `spark-ec2` will ever have that capability, since all of the setup scripts it uses assume a Linux host.

That said, Databricks recently announced a [community-managed index of Spark packages](http://spark-packages.org/), and people are adding in stuff there all the time. For example, there is already a package to let you [launch Spark clusters on Google's Compute Engine](http://spark-packages.org/package/9).

Though there doesn't currently appear to be anything for you, I would keep my eye on that community index for something that lets you launch Windows Spark clusters on EC2.

Comment: This info was very useful! I might start thinking about porting my project into a Linux environment to ease the further work. However, I will keep an eye on that spark packages site. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In a resource with Spark Packages, suggested by Nick, you can see recently added project by Sigmoid Analytics - that lets you launch the Spark cluster on Azure - `spark_azure`:

https://github.com/sigmoidanalytics/spark_azure

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I am afraid I am looking for Windows support, and if I am not mistaken the project you mention is only available for Linux machines.